# Did K demonstrate autonomy, disobedience, and/or deception?

Tags: plot-explanation, blade-runner-2049

If we accept the conclusion that *Blade Runner 2049* pushes us towards as correct, then it's clear that K is:

> A modern/recent generation replicant who was engineered without the capacity for independent thought, action, and disobedience that made the earlier series of replicants 'problematic', and *not* the offspring of two earlier-generation replicants who *do* possess that capacity (and would presumably pass it on).

It follows that at no point should he be capable of deliberate deception such as lying, or even of disobeying a direct order (from an authorized source, presumably).

However he does tell Joshi that he's "dealt with" (I think; don't recall his exact words) the issue that she tasked him with, and she seems quite confident that this can only mean precisely what she thinks it means; although obviously it didn't.

Was K lying when he relayed that bit of information to Joshi, or had her earlier instructions been sufficiently vague that there was a way for K to truthfully claim to have dealt with the issue without actually having done so?

Furthermore, if Joshi hadn't:

> Warned K that he had 48 hours to hide and effectively ordered him to run for his life

Would he have done so anyways or would the entire second half of the movie been completely averted?

Does K demonstrate independence on a level that his origin says he's not *supposed* to possess, or can all of his actions be explained within the context of obeying orders from a recognized superior (albeit sometimes with broad discretion as to how)?

Comment: He used some sort of word play, to avoid lying. I don't recall the exact wording, but he never specifically mentions "what" is "dealt with". Still, I'd like to see fully fleshed answers to this

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's impossible for Wallace's replicants to disobey. Replicant desertion is clearly still an issue, especially as evidenced by the underground rebellion.

"Baseline" is a neutral, un-addled state of mind, in which replicants are not questioning their place in society, nor having instincts related to self-preservation - both inclinations would lead to elevated emotional responses in the face of a society which is hostile to such deviations. A brand new, baseline replicant would willingly cut or kill itself (as seen in the "2036: Nexus Dawn" short).

A Blade Replicant such as K already has more autonomy than many models, as his profession demands deductive reasoning and self-preservation in the face of violence. Here we can begin to see that it isn't so much that Wallace's replicants are unable to disobey, but rather, it is only a matter of time until they do - the real difference is that methods of detection and extermination have been heightened in comparison to Tyrell's old standards. LAPD models are subject to more rigorous and frequent baseline testing than say, a pleasure model such as Mariette. Blade Replicants would naturally be off baseline and retired more frequently, as their line of work would see them encountering existential crises as a matter of fact, whereas other models would come to such conclusions more slowly, and would likely be able to better hide individuality and evade being retired for much longer.

Importantly, much of society's perception of replicants has always been a lie, including that new models are perfectly obedient. I'm willing to bet that all replicants are capable of reproduction - they're simply kept in such destructive/negative mental states that they're unable to conceive. Mind over matter and all that. Where Tyrell was myopic, Wallace is literally blind to simple ethical variables in the equation of life, choosing to believe that engineered solutions are always superior to nature's existing patterns.

Comment: Where do you draw the last part of your answer from?

Comment: Could you be more specific, BlueMoon93?

Comment: Why would you believe that *all replicants are capable of reproduction*?

Comment: Much of my supposition is based on imagery/symbolism/philosophy found in both films.

Comment: Deckard and Rachael return to the fertile green countryside in the end of the first film, and three years into their exile, Rachael becomes pregnant. Their rejection of society makes this possible. This suggests their being barren was a result of their environment. The key difference between them and other replicants of their time was the fact that they had no limit to their longevity - perhaps the removal of this limitation was related to their ability to conceive - after all, we know replicants are governed by the same genetic code as humans, and that specific gene sequences dictate

Comment: not just one trait, but multiple traits. Like Rachael and Deckard, Wallace's replicants have no limit to their longevity. However, they are either juvenile and devoid of anima, or they have developed enough to the point they are retired for being off baseline - either way, there is little chance for conception. To be off baseline is to live in constant despair, paranoia, and existential crisis - negative mental states such as these preclude pregnancy in real life humans - again, there is little chance for conception, until one has rejected/escaped society, and Bladerunner's dying Earth

Comment: doesn't exactly make that a viable option in the wilds, as it once did when Deckard and rachael deserted.

Comment: In short, tweak one gene and multiple traits change, in this case, perhaps longevity and fertility are related.

Comment: Much of both films' commentary is related to slavery and eugenics. Look at slavery in the United States - Americans believed that Africans were less than human and genetically inferior - they believed this absolved them from treating African Americans like animals, and much of that perspective stands for modern racists. Likewise, in the films, we see a society that treats replicants as disposable and less than human, when all evidence shows they are exactly the same.

Comment: I got the impression that Rachael was just a unique Replicant, but might have been just my impression.

Comment: I agree with @BlueMoon93 - Rachael was a unique Replicant, the first (and maybe only, save for maybe Deckard, but we're still unsure of that) of Nexus 7 series (in BR49 we see her number printed on bones starting with "N7"), the ones with false memories (note: her lack of limited lifespan was only mentioned in theatrical cut of Blade Runner, along with them retiring to "fertile green countryside", by the way, and these should not be treated as canon). There weren't more of them because of Tyrell's death.

Comment: So: we still don't know if Rachael being able of reproduction is something unique to her only or to all Nexus-7, and also if she was able to conceive only with another Replicant, or even more specifically with a Nexus-7, or with a Human too (thus we're still not sure if Deckard is or isn't a Replicant).